# Couchbase .NET SDK Connection Issue "Unable to locate node"

Tags: .net, windows, couchbase

I installed Couchbase server (2.2) on a windows server 2012 r3. And using 1.3.4 .net client. When i try to connect i got an exception: "Unable to locate node 146". 
I also have another couchbase server (2.2) on a windows 2008 r2. I'm using same configuration, and no problem when i connect to 2008 server.

Tried other couchbase servers (2.5.x) but the result is the same. What can be the problem? CouchbaseServer doesn't support windowsserver2012?

Answer (score 0):

[http://www.couchbase.com/issues/browse/MB-9494?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:all-tabpanel](http://www.couchbase.com/issues/browse/MB-9494?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3aall-tabpanel)

They say:

We need to support Windows Server 2012 R2 in production for 3.0.